# Snowflake cluster Security in multi tenancy

Tags: security, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, multi-tenant, ddos

For multi-tenant environments with snowflake different clusters for each client. How can we secure the snowflake cluster via a DDoS attack?
As we have common microservices across tenants than one tenant can maliciously make DDoS attack on another snowflake cluster.
How can we configure network isolation in between tenant snowflakes clusters?

Thanks

Comment: Hi  - what do you actually mean by “cluster” in this context? I’m pretty sure that’s not the correct Snowflake terminology for whatever it is you are trying to describe

Comment: Hi Nick sorry for the terminology. Referring cluster means a different account in the organization.

Comment: If you’re talking about separate accounts per tenant then the answer from @fkayani probably covers it

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake maintains a comprehensive documented security program based on NIST 800-53 (or industry recognized successor framework), under which Snowflake implements and maintains physical, administrative, and technical safeguards designed to protect the confidentiality, integrity, availability, and security of the Service and Customer Data (the “Security Program”), including, but not limited to, as set forth below. Snowflake regularly tests and evaluates its Security Program, and may review and update its Security Program as well as this Security Addendum, provided, however, that such updates shall be designed to enhance and not materially diminish the Security Program.

More details: [SECURITY ADDENDUM](https://www.snowflake.com/legal/security-addendum/#content)

Comment: Hi @fkayani, sorry I am not referring to the snowflake account/cluster security. I want to know in our design how do we secure a different account/cluster with a common service. Is there any network-level isolation we can do for a different account so that only allowable account is assessable .

Comment: For Network security or isolation, snowflake best practices are as follows:

Use network policies
Use private connectivity with Snowflake.
Allow firewall to connect client applications to Snowflake.
Allow Snowflake to access your cloud storage location for loading/unloading data.

Details: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowflake-Security-Overview-and-Best-Practices